# Search button is being pushed to new line on some browsers on search form

Tags: html, css, vbulletin

Facing a problem specifically on phones and tablets is the misaligned blue search icon on the top left. Not sure how to fix this.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Live:

[www.talkjesus.com](http://www.talkjesus.com) (view on tablet or mobile phone, works on desktop)

Comment: Can you give example code, what have you tried?

Comment: OP: what is the CSS for the header? Please change the title of your question to reflect the code problem you are having.

Comment: The internet works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In main-rollup.css, change the css class from**

```
.globalsearch input.textbox {
   height: 22px;
   width: 218px;
   border: none;
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

**to**

```
.globalsearch input.textbox {
   height: 22px;
   width: 212px;
   border: none;
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

Note the shortened width of the textbox. I believe it is pushing the search button to a new line on some browsers.

**Alternatively, you can place the button like this:**

- Set "position: relative" css on the form
- Set "position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;" on the search button
- Adjust "right" and "top" css for the search button until it is in the correct spot